# Syntax for targeting class inside element with var in Id?

Tags: jquery, syntax, targeting

What is the correct syntax for targeting a class which is a child element of an element with an id that includes a variable.

Without the var it works:

```
$( "#parent_el .child-class" )
```

What's the correct syntax if you add a variable, like so?

```
$( "#parent_el_" + uniqueIdForParent .child-class )
```

Comment: `$( "#parent_el_" +uniqueIdForParent+ " .child-class")`? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyhwsspj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation:

```js
var id = "1";
$("#parent_" +id+ " .child").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent_1"><p class="child">Foo</p></div>
```

Also, you can use  [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```js
var id = "1";
$("#parent_"+id).find('.child').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent_1"><p class="child">Bar</p></div>
```